# Бинарный поиск: поиск количества элементов

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

В отсортированном массиве (*числа могут повторяться*) нужно максимально быстро найти количество раз, которое встречается каждый запрошенный (*запросы также могут повторяться*) элемент, причем вывести найденные количества в том порядке, в каком они были запрошены.

Уже используется бинарный поиск.

---

**Пример 1.**

Входные данные:

**1 2 3 4 5 6** *(массив)*

**0 6 2 1 11** *(запрошенные числа)*

Выходные данные:

**0 1 1 1 0** *(количество вхождений для каждого числа соответственно)*

---

**Пример 2.**

Входные данные:

**1 1 1 1 1** *(массив)*

**1 1** *(запрошенные числа)*

Выходные данные:

**5 5** *(количество вхождений для каждого числа соответственно)*

---

Поскольку последовательность чисел отсортирована, была идея отсортировать и запрошенные числа по возрастанию, чтобы, найдя число или последовательность одинаковых чисел, исключить их из выборки, сдвинув левую границу для бинарного поиска на количество таких чисел вправо. То есть, не рассматривать числа, количество которых и так уже посчитано. Такое решение оптимально, но не сохраняет порядка запросов (*количества вхождений выводятся в порядке возрастания запрошенных чисел, а не в порядке их ввода*).
В связи с этим вопрос: как реализовать одновременно быстрый - со сдвигом границы - алгоритм бинарного поиска и при этом вывести найденные количества в том порядке, в котором они были запрошены?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int findIndex(vector<int> arr, int n, int element)
{
    if (element > arr[n - 1])
    {
        return -1;
    }
    int left = 0, right = n - 1;
    
    while (right > left)
    {
        int middle = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (element > arr[middle])
        {
            left = middle + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            right = middle;
        }
    }
    if (arr[left] == element)
    {
        return left;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
int findQuanity(vector<int> arr, int n, int index)
{
    int element = arr[index];
    int quanity = 0;
    while (element == arr[index])
    {
        quanity++;
        if (index + 1 <= n - 1)
        {
            index++;
        }
        else break;
    }
    return quanity;
}
int main()
{
    int members;
    int element;
    cin >> members;
    
    vector<int> marks(members);

    for (int i = 0; i < members; i++)
    {
        cin >> marks[i];
    }
    int requests;
    cin >> requests;
    for (int i = 0; i < requests; i++)
    {
        cin >> element;
        int index = findIndex(marks, members, element);
        int quanity = 0;
        if (index > -1)
        {
            quanity = findQuanity(marks, members, index);
        }
        cout << quanity << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: ну можешь попробовать скопировать массив с запросами, его отсортировать, и по нем выполнить поиск , а результаты положить в мап, и, после, при выводе идти по исходному массиву и выводить данные из мапа?

Comment: А зачем вам как-то мучиться, пытаясь выжать дополнительную скорость?

Comment: @EzikBro Задачка такая, проверку не проходит (время работы не больше секунды)

Comment: Я предполагаю, что вам нужно не извращаться, а смотреть, что вы там понаписали такое, что работает дольше секунды. Какие у вас в задаче ограничения на входные данные?

Comment: @EzikBro Количество чисел не более миллиона, количество запросов не более двухсот тысяч. Числа в последовательности не более 10^9, числа в запросах не более 10^9 + 1.
P.S. Сейчас добавлю код, который не проходит ограничение по времени.

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема не в алгоритме, а в скорости ввода/вывода. Вы что используете, `std::cin` и `std::cout`?

Comment: @EzikBro Прошу прощения.. Есть альтернатива? Стоит сейчас покурить мануалы на тему ввода/вывода?

Comment: Добавьте в начало `main` такие строки: `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(); cout.tie();`

Comment: А, так конечно у вас TLE. Просто представьте как отработает ваша программа на тесте из миллиона единиц и двухсот тысяч запросов по единице. Она будет каждый запрос проходить целый массив. Вам нужно также бинпоиском находить последний элемент, равный запросу, а не только самый первый.

Comment: Еще рекомендую вам посмотреть на `lower_bound` и `upper_bound` - встроенные алгоритмы бинарного поиска, которые оптимизированы и вылизаны настолько, что вы при всем желании быстрее них не напишите.

Comment: Есть какие то ограничения по памяти? Почему нельзя всю исходную последовательность сложить с словарь, где ключ - элемент последовательности,  а значение - количество повторений элемента? Это можно построить за линейное время, а после каждый запрос будет выполняться за константу.

Comment: @tym32167 вы, видимо, плохо знаете устройство бинарных деревьев - за линейное время у вас никак не получиться это сделать. Ровно как и запрос в дереве не может быть константой. У бинарных деревьев поиска, если не ошибаюсь, логарифмическая сложность

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я очень хорошо знаю бинарные деревья, н причем тут это? В моем комментарии нет ничего о бинартных деревьях.  Я предложил построить хештаблицу, свойство хештаблицы - это константное время доступа по ключу.

Comment: @tym32167 конкретно хэш-таблицу вы все же не упомянули, а лишь словарь. Я предположил, что вы говорите о `map`, так как он гораздо более распространенный чем `unordered_map`. Но да, если использовать хэш-таблицу, то ваше утверждение верно

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch я понял, это недопонимание возникло просто из за того, что у нас с вами разный стек технологий. Попросту в C# хеш таблица называется [Dictionary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1). Но хорошо, что разобрались.

Comment: `unordered_map`. Один раз пройтись, потом любой запрос - О(1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раз в тэгах стоит `c++`, а массив является отсортированным, то сам Страуструп велел использовать стандартные алгоритмы `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` и `distance`. В коде это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```cpp
  auto first = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), val);
  auto last = std::upper_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), val);

  int count = std::distance(first, last);
  std::cout << count << std::endl;
```

Быстрее у вас вряд ли получится, разве что все это дело на Си написать

UPD обнаружил, что мой код не совсем рационален: поиск последнего элемента можно ускорить, так как мы знаем где находится первый

```cpp
auto last = std::upper_bound(first, vec.end(), val);
```

Comment: Еще можно посмотреть после поиска lower_bound на следующий элемент и не вызывать upper_bound если он отличен от только что найденного

Comment: @avp ну это смотря насколько это распространенный случай